# Abstract algebra algorithms

Tags: algorithm-design, algebra

Let’s make a big list of algorithms relying on abstract algebra. This will help us see how ubiquitous algebra is in algorithm design. I’ll start with two: one is the General Number Field Sieve, the other is Babai’s graph isomorphism algorithm.

Comment: Many decoding and list decoding algorithms in coding theory come to mind. Also primality testing, factoring polynomials and discrete logarithm.

Comment: "Let's make a big list" questions are usually too broad to be a good fit here.  Any community votes?

Comment: When proposing a "big list" question, one thing that would help is to motivate why you are interested in examples of this. If that is well-explained then it could be more useful. If you just say "Let's make a big list" it's hard to argue that it's a good question for the site.